# Upgrading early beta ASP.NET Core Project to another early beta gives error when opening in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

*This question is about an obsolete beta version and could maybe be deleted*

A small app based on the "ASP.NET 5 preview template" (now called ASP.NET Core) when opened in Visual Studio 2015 after installing DNX beta7 and the ASP.NET Visual Studio Tools for Beta 7, gives the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Cannot find DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12256' required by 
your solution. Do you want to install it now? If you select No, 
‘dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7’ will be used as the solution DNX SDK version
for this session.
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Choosing Yes causes the following message box and the following error output in the DNVM output pane:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6-12256' failed to install. 
The solution will use DNX SDK version ‘dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7’ for 
this session.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

DNVM output panel:

```
There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed 
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:563 char:9
+         throw "There are no runtimes matching the name $RuntimeId on  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (There are no ru...get.org/api 
   /v2.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr- 
   win-x86 on feed https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.

There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr-win-x86 on feed 
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:563 char:9
+         throw "There are no runtimes matching the name $RuntimeId on  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (There are no ru...etvnext/api 
   /v2.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : There are no runtimes matching the name dnx-clr- 
   win-x86 on feed https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2.
```

Interestingly when I run `dnvm` command to list DNX runtimes, from my powershell, it lists 1.0.0-beta5,beta6,beta7 as installed and present in my `c:\Users\USERNAME\.dnx\runtimes` folder.

What is going on and how does one fix this problem?

Comment: I suggest create a new project and compare changes vs your previous project to update the previous project. update the project.json file(s), the global.json, web.config if it exists in wwwroot folder may also need to be updated to reference beta7. Also note that the latest project will put a Nuget.config file in solution items that references https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, so you probably also need to add that.

Comment: Does your project have a `global.json`?

Comment: There's a project.json that appears to need updates, but the global.json appears to have already been set to be equal to whatever is in the project settings dialog.

Comment: Can you post your project.json?

Comment: I believe that the actual problem is that you just CAN'T take an .xproj and in-place-update it using only the IDE. You must abandon your beta6 solution and .xproj and project.json and global.json and the general overall structure, generate a NEW project, and add your own sources, beta7 requires this.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this (tested with RC):

```
dnvm update-self
dnvm upgrade
```

Ref: http://myonlineband.com/Help/Wiki/Computers/Programming/Solving-Missing-Default-DNX-Issues

Comment: RC1 or RC1-Update1? Which RC?